# Nginx Proxy to Files on Local Disk or S3

Tags: proxy, amazon-s3, nginx

So I'm moving my site away from Apache and onto Nginx, and I'm having trouble with this scenario:

User uploads a photo. This photo is resized, and then copied to S3. If there's suitable room on disk (or the file cannot be transferred to S3), a local version is kept.

I want requests for these images (such as http://www.mysite.com/p/1_1.jpg) to first look in the p/ directory. If no local file exists, I want to proxy the request out to S3 and render the image (but not redirect).

In Apache, I did this like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+_[0-9]+\.jpg)$ http://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [P,L]
```

My attempt to replicate this behavior in Nginx is this:

```
location /p/ {
    if (-e $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    proxy_pass http://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

What happens is that every request attempts to hit Amazon S3, even if the file exists on disk (and if it doesn't exist on Amazon, I get errors.) If I remove the proxy_pass line, then requests for files on disk DO work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share virual.conf file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Shouldn't this be an example of using `try_files`?

```
location /p/ {
    try_files $uri @s3;
}

location @s3{ 
    proxy_pass http://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

Make sure there isn't a following slash on the S3 url

Comment: Great answer! Clear and simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You could improve your s3 proxy config like this. Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44749584:

```
location /p/ {
    try_files $uri @s3;
}

location @s3 {
  set $s3_bucket        'your_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com';
  set $url_full         '$1';

  proxy_http_version     1.1;
  proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
  proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
  proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  resolver               8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout       10s;
  proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket$url_full;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to keep my coderwall post :) For the caching purpose you can improve it a bit:

```
http {

  proxy_cache_path          /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=S3_CACHE:10m inactive=24h max_size=500m;
  proxy_temp_path           /tmp/cache/temp;

  server {
    location ~* ^/cache/(.*) {
      proxy_buffering        on;
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
      ...
      proxy_cache            S3_CACHE;
      proxy_cache_valid      24h;
      proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/$url_full;
    }
  }

}
```

One more recommendation is to extend resolver cache upto 5 min:

```
resolver                  8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout          10s;
```

Comment: You don't need a  trailing slash in **proxy_pass** directive, it's quite important. It  should look like this: 
`proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket$url_full;`

Answer (score 0):

`break` isn't doing quite what you expect nginx will do the last thing you ask of it, which makes sense if you start digging around making modules... but basically protect your proxy_pass with the *does-not-exist* version

```
if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
}
if(!-f $request_filename)
    proxy_pass  http://s3;
}
```

Comment: I tried that initially, but Nginx won't start if I have the full `http://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/` in the `proxy_pass` call. I get the following error:

`Restarting nginx: 2010/01/11 20:53:36 [emerg] 1485#0: "proxy_pass" may not have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside the "if" statement, or inside the "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_site.com:39`

If I remove the trailing slash, Nginx will start, but my requests do not get routed correctly any more. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by checking to see if the file doesn't exist, and if so, rewriting that request. I then handle the re-written request and do the proxy_pass there, like so:

```
location /p/ {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/p/(.*)$ /ps3/$1 last;
    break;
  }
}

location /ps3/ {
  proxy_pass http://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

Comment: The `if` in nginx has very unpredictable behaviour. Even though this works fine, it's recommended to use `try_files` whenever possible, like in Dan Gayle's answer. Check http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil for the subtleties of `if`.