# Nginx proxy Amazon S3 resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, proxy, http-headers

I´m performing some WPO tasks, so PageSpeed suggested me to leverage browser caching. I have improved it successfully for some static files in my Nginx server, however my image files stored in Amazon S3 server are still missing.

I have read an approach regarding update each file in S3 to include some header metatags (Expires and Cache-Control). I think this is not a good approach. I have thousands of files, so this is not feasible for me.

I think a most convenient approach is to configure my Nginx 1.6.0 server to proxy the S3 files. I have read about this, but I´m not skilled at all on server config, so I got a couple examples from these sites: https://gist.github.com/benjaminbarbe/1961db5ffbaad57eff12

I added this location code inside my server block in my nginx config file:

```
#inside server block
location /mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ {


        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_set_header       Host mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;      
        proxy_pass             http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
      }
```

For sure, this is not working for me. No header is included in my requests. So, first I think the requests are not matching the locations.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:90810
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Fri, 23 Jun 2017 04:53:56 GMT
ETag:"4fd0be549fbcaf9b47c18a15146cdf16"
Last-Modified:Tue, 09 Jun 2015 09:47:13 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:cKsq1qRra74DqVsTewh3P3sgzVUoPR8aAT2NFCuwA+JjCdDZfk7/7x/C0WPjBa51GEb4C8LyAIc=
x-amz-request-id:94EADB4EDD3DE1C1
```

Comment: Maybe modify Cache-Control for the existing objects via scripting e.g. https://chriskief.com/2014/07/13/setting-s3-cache-metadata/.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Nginx config to add any headers. Further, the `proxy_hide_header` directives are being ignored, and nginx by default should have scrubbed `Server:`.  So... are you sure this request was actually handled by Nginx?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No. I don´t know almost anything about server configuring. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are right. I think the request is not been handled by Nginx. This is a resource request example: http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg How can I set the location? @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Without knowing what framework/environment you're using, it's hard to guess how the base URLs might be configured.

Comment: AngularJS 1.0.7 running in the Nginx server.

Comment: Have you looked into using CloudFront for this? It's trivial to set up with S3 and will set these headers automatically as well as be globally available.

Comment: You may want to check out this reference implementation of NGINX proxying S3 using njs: https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway/

Answer (score 196):

Your approach to proxy S3 files via Nginx makes a lot of sense. It solves number of problems and comes with extra benefits such masking URLs, proxy cache, speed up transferring by offload SSL/TLS. You do it almost right, let me show what is left to make it perfect.

> For sample queries I use the S3 bucket and an image URL mentioned in the [public comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639182/nginx-proxy-amazon-s3-resources/44749584#comment76284516_44639182) to the original question.

We start with inspecting of Amazon S3 files' headers

```
curl -I http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 17:49:10 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT
ETag: "37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jul 2018 07:41:49 UTC
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 378843
Server: AmazonS3
```

We can see missing Cache-Control but Conditional GET headers have already been configured. When we reuse E-Tag/Last-Modified (that's how a browser's client side cache works), we get HTTP 304 alongside with empty Content-Length. An interpretation of that is client (curl in our case) queries the resource saying that no data transfer required unless file has been modified on the server:

```
curl -I http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg 
--header "If-None-Match: 37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 17:53:33 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT
ETag: "37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jul 2018 07:41:49 UTC
Server: AmazonS3

curl -I http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg 
--header "If-Modified-Since: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 18:17:34 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT
ETag: "37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jul 2018 07:41:49 UTC
Server: AmazonS3
```

> "PageSpeed suggested to leverage browser caching" that means 
>   Cache=control is missing. Nginx as proxy for S3 files solves 
>   not only problem with missing headers but also saves traffic 
>   using Nginx proxy cache.

I use macOS but Nginx configuration works on Linux exactly the same way without modifications. Step by step:

1.Install Nginx

```
brew update && brew install nginx
```

2.Setup Nginx to proxy S3 bucket, see configuration below

3.Request the file via Nginx. Please take a look at the **Server** header, we see Nginx rather than Amazon S3 now:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/s3/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 18:30:26 GMT
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 378843
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT
ETag: "37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jul 2018 07:41:49 UTC
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

[image: Request the file via Nginx]

4.Request the file using Nginx proxy with Conditional GET:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/s3/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg 
--header "If-None-Match: 37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 18:32:16 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT
ETag: "37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jul 2018 07:41:49 UTC
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

[image: Request the file using Nginx proxy with Conditional GET]

5.Request the file using Nginx proxy cache, please take a look at **X-Cache-Status** header, its value is MISS until cache warmed up after first request

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/s3_cached/img/blog/sailing-routes-around-croatia-central-dalmatia-islands/yachts-anchored-paradise-cove-croatia-3.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 18:40:45 GMT
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 378843
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:42:31 GMT
ETag: "37a907fc5dd7cfd0c428af78f09e95a9"
Expires: Fri, 21 Jul 2018 07:41:49 UTC
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
X-Cache-Status: HIT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

[image: Request the file using Nginx proxy cache]

Based on [Nginx official documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) I provide the Nginx S3 configuration with optimised caching settings that supports the following options:

- **proxy_cache_revalidate** instructs NGINX to use conditional GET
  requests when refreshing content from the origin servers
- the updating parameter to the **proxy_cache_use_stale** directive instructs NGINX to deliver stale content when clients request an item
  while an update to it is being downloaded from the origin server,
  instead of forwarding repeated requests to the server
- with **proxy_cache_lock** enabled, if multiple clients request a file that is not current in the cache (a MISS), only the first of those
  requests is allowed through to the origin server

**Nginx configuration**:

```
worker_processes  1;
daemon off;

error_log  /dev/stdout info;
pid        /usr/local/var/nginx/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  default_type       text/html;
  access_log         /dev/stdout;
  sendfile           on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  proxy_cache_path   /tmp/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=s3_cache:10m max_size=500m
                     inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

  server {
    listen 8080;

    location /s3/ {
      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_set_header       Connection "";
      proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
      proxy_set_header       Host yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
      proxy_pass             http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/;
    }

    location /s3_cached/ {
      proxy_cache            s3_cache;
      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_set_header       Connection "";
      proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
      proxy_set_header       Host yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
      proxy_cache_revalidate on;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_cache_lock       on;
      proxy_cache_valid      200 304 60m;
      add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
      add_header             X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
      proxy_pass             http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Anatoly, thanks for your work. I'm trying to using it, but its still producing "MISS" caching while I add `proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;`
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: the config above should work, not sure if I understand what do you mean by problem help anyone, let's solve the problem instead :). Can you attach curl command and Nginx config so can I reproduce it?

Comment: @OlegMykolaichenko I experience the same problem. It is always MISS. Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: More details please, how can I replicate?

Comment: I directly copied the code block you added. However, when I added `proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;`It started to HIT. I believe that it might be related with NginX versions. Mine was 1.6.0 Thank you @Anatoly and @OlegMykolaichenko!

Comment: Updated with proxy_cache_valid directive

Answer (score 5):

Without the details of which modules Nginx is compiled with, we can say two ways for adding Expires and Cache-Control headers to all files.

**Nginx S3 proxy**

This is what you asked about -- using Nginx to add expire, cache-control headers on S3 files.

Nginx [this set-misc-nginx-module needed](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module) to support Nginx S3 proxy & change/add expire, cache-control on the fly. [This is a standard full guide](https://dodwell.us/using-nginx-to-proxy-private-amazon-s3-web-services.html) from compilation to usage, this is [great guide for nginx-extras for Ubuntu server](http://asiantux.blogspot.in/2016/11/customizing-built-in-modules-of-your.html). This is [full guide with example with WordPress](https://devgeniem.github.io/wp-project/uploads/s3/).

There are more S3 modules for extra things. Without those modules Nginx will not understand and config test (`nginx -t`) will pass test with wrong config. `set-misc-nginx-module` is minimum for your need. What you want has [better example on this Github gist](https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/9639593).

As not all are used with compilation and the setup is really slightly difficult, I am also writing the way to set  Expires and Cache-Control header for all files in one Amazon S3 bucket.

**Amazon S3 Bucket Expires and Cache-Control Header**

Also, it is possible to set Expires and Cache-Control headers for all objects in one AWS S3 bucket with script or command line. There are several such free libraries and scripts on Github [like this one](https://github.com/ember-cli-deploy/ember-cli-deploy-s3), [bucket explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-set-cache-control-header-for-s3-object.html), [Amazon's tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#options), [Amazon's this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html) and [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html). Command will be like this for that cp CLI tool :

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE \
--expires 2027-09-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read --cache-control max-age=2000000,public
```

Answer (score -4):

From an architectural review, what you're trying to do is a wrong way to go about:

- Amazon S3 is presumably optimised to be a highly available cache; by introducing a hand-rolled proxying layer on top of it, you're merely introducing an unnecessary extra delay and a huge point of failure, and also losing all the benefits that would come out of S3
- Your performance analysis with regards to the number of files is incorrect.  If you have thousands of files on S3, the correct solution would be to write a one-time script to change the requisite attributes on S3, instead of hand-rolling a proxying mechanism that you don't fully understand, and that would be executed many times over (ad nauseam).  Doing the proxying would likely be a band-aid, and, in reality, will likely decrease the performance, not increase it (even if you'd get to have a stateless automated tool tell you otherwise).  Not to mention that it would also be an unnecessary resource drain, and may contribute to actual performance issues and heisenbugs down the line.

---

That said, if you're still up for proxying with adding the headers, the correct way to do so with nginx would be by using the [**`expires`**](http://nginx.org/r/expires) directive.

E.g., you may place `expires max;` before or after your `proxy_pass` directive within the appropriate location.

The `expires` directive automatically takes care of setting a correct `Cache-Control` header for you, too; but you could also use [**`add_header`**](http://nginx.org/r/add_header) directive should you wish to add any custom response headers manually.

Comment: FWIW, S3 is definitely highly available, but it's not meant as a cache and is relatively expensive to use at high volumes. That's why Amazon themselves offer CloudFront with S3 support. If you intend on serving high volumes, you should not be doing it directly out of S3. So putting some form of cache is not a bad idea t all.