# Serve S3 resources via http/2

Tags: amazon-s3, http2

Our web app that we are building is having a lot of its assets served via S3. When looking at them in Chrome they are being served via HTTP and not http/2.

Is there a config setting in S3 or a header that we could pass that would tell S3 to attempt to serve assets via http/2 if the client supports it?

I'm having issues finding any resources online about how to do this or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Serve via CloudFront, there is a manual in the article

   [New – HTTP/2 Support for Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/aws/new-http2-support-for-cloudfront/)
2. Serve via your own proxy. Nginx configuration for such magic is deeply explained here:

   [Nginx proxy Amazon S3 resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639182/nginx-proxy-amazon-s3-resources/44749584#44749584)

In both options you should have SSL certificate generated for the domain you use to serve resources from S3.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you need direct S3 access using HTTP2 rather than using a proxy server. I was looking for such feature too but it seems that AWS S3 do not have HTTP2 support yet. 
BTW, google cloud storage have this feature though.