# Could aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony make use of h2 protocol to multipart upload files to an S3 bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, http2, aws-sdk-php-symfony

First of all, apologies if the question exists but I couldn't find anything exactly like this when searching stackoverflow. The closest one being [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471590/serve-s3-resources-via-http-2) which is a bit outdated.

Secondly, we're using the PHP bundle `aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony` to instantiate an S3 client. We're using it to do multipartuploads to S3. Everything works fine but when looking in the network, the protocol is http/1.1.

The flow looks like this:

- our front-end client consumes our API;
- our API returns an S3 upload path (generated by the S3 client);
- our front-end does chunking the file and then PUTs it to the given S3 API url;
- when all chunks are uploaded successfully, we tell our API the upload is done for some extra steps;
- we also handle the abort process.

A couple of questions:

1. I'm wondering if we can somehow "force" the bundle to use h2 instead of http1.1?
2. If we'd be able to use h2, would that let the browser make all HTTP parts calls at once?
3. Would switching to h2 (if possible) decrease the upload process to the S3 bucket?

We know that browsers are limiting the number of HTTP calls to the same domain to 6-8 (Chrome has 6) over http/1.1 but multiplexing those over h2 and h3. If I understood it correctly or feel free to correct/guide me.

[image]

Thank you in advance!